# Android ViewPager - How to force removal of all items?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, kotlin

I am writing an Android app which makes extensive use of ViewPagers that contain high-res images. I am extending PagerAdapter and manually creating and destroying items when appropriate. It works fine until this fragment gets placed on that backstack. I would like to remove all images from memory when the fragment with ViewPagers gets placed on the backstack, but I can't figure out a way.

I tried removing all the backing data from the list that the adapter uses, then call .notifyDataSetChanged(), but this doesn't go through and call PagerAdapter.destroyItem() for each page like I hope.

I also tried using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, but this also didn't seem to clear out any memory during app usage.

**How can I force a PagerAdapter to call destroyItem() on all items in a pager?**

Here is my code for the View that contains the ViewPager:

```
class ContentStrip : LinearLayout {

    var title : WeakReference<TextView>? = null
    var titleString: String = ""
    lateinit var pager : WeakReference<MyViewPager>
    var data:ContentCollection? = null

    //[...] other view methods

    //Called from parent fragment's onDestroy
    fun clearMemory() {
        if (data == null) return
        var i = -1
        var contentItem : ContentItem
        for(item in data!!.contentItems) {
            i++
            var v:View? = pager.get().findViewWithTag("${titleString}$i") ?: continue
            contentItem = v as ContentItem
            contentItem.image?.setImageDrawable(null)
            contentItem.image = null
            removeView(contentItem)
        }
        title = null
        pager.get().removeAllViews()
        data?.contentItems?.clear()
        pager.get().adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        invalidate()
    }

    class ContentStripAdapter() : PagerAdapter() {

        lateinit var outer: WeakReference<ContentStrip>

        fun setOuterRef(cs:ContentStrip) : ContentStripAdapter {
            outer = WeakReference(cs)
            return this
        }

        //[...]other PagerAdapter methods

        override fun destroyItem (container:ViewGroup, position:Int, obj:Any) {
            var img : ContentItem? = obj as ContentItem
            img?.image?.setImageDrawable(null)
            img?.image = null
            img?.title = null
            container.removeView(img)
            img = null
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return outer.get().data?.contentItems?.count()!!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try using simple views instead of fragments in viewpager? I had similar issue in one of my project and imageView.setImageDrawable(null); worked for me. But fragments were not need so i just used a ViewGroup with ImageViews and TextViews.

Comment: try to use a FragmentStatePager adapter, and on getItemPosition method just return POSITION_NONE.

Answer (score 2):

`PagerAdapter.destroyItem()` is not called because the default implementation of `Psger.getItemPosition()` returns `PagerAdapter.POSITION_UNCHANGED`. So when you call `PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` `ViewPager` continues to think that items you removed still exist and doesn't destroy them. You need to return `PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE` for each item removed from the adapter.

Comment: Calling `PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE` its not a good solution, if other views not required to be re-instantiate. Is there any other solution without `re-instantiate PagerAdapter` can we achieve that?

Comment: You have to return `POSITION_NONE` only for items you want to remove.

Comment: yes exactly i am returning `POSITION_NONE` for selected item to remove from view pager but again it re-instantiate PagerAdapter i.e. pager adapter reset.